# How can I not use a global variable in this embedded program?

Tags: java, while-loop, global-variables, global, static-variables

I believe we have an edge case in our firm, which prevents me from entering the "never use global variables camp".

We need to write an embedded application which works in our box, that pulls medical data from devices in hospital.

That should run infinitely, even when medical device is plugged off, network is gone, or settings of our box changes. Settings are read from a .txt file, which can be changed during runtime with preferably no trouble.

That is why Singleton pattern is no use to me. So we go back from time to time (after 1000 data is read) and read settings like so:

```
public static SettingForIncubator settings;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true){
        settings = getSettings(args);

        int counter=0;

        while(medicalDeviceIsGivingData && counter < 1000){
            byte[] data = readData(); //using settings

            //a lot of of other functions that use settings.

            counter++;
        }
        Thread.Sleep(100); //against overheating and CPU usage.
    } 
    public byte[] readData(){
    //read Data from the port described in settings variable
    }
}
```

Is there any other way I can design the program?

Comment: This code isn't using the global `settings` inside the loop.

Comment: ```while(true)``` with no ```Thread.sleep``` will make your cpu get 100% soon

Comment: of course I use Thread.sleep(). and I use settings inside readData(). I'll add them in pseudo code.

Comment: @OnatKorucu you have defined "settings" as a Class variable and then again in main function, when one is being used inside readData() ?

Comment: @BHAWANI SINGH you are right, in pseudocode I accidentally defined settings twice. I am fixing it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly you mean, but I think this code will help you something:

```java
class SettingsForIncubator {
}

public class MedicalProcessor {

    protected volatile boolean active;
    protected volatile boolean medicalDeviceIsGivingData;

    public void start(String[] args) throws Exception {
        this.active = true;
        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> loop(args));
        thread.start();
    }

    protected void loop(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("start");
        while(active) {
            SettingsForIncubator settings = getSettings(args);
            int counter=0;

            while(medicalDeviceIsGivingData && counter < 1000){
                byte[] data = readData(settings); //using settings

                //a lot of of other functions that use settings.

                counter++;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100); //against overheating and CPU usage.
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected byte[] readData(SettingsForIncubator settings) {
        // logic read data
        return null;
    }

    protected SettingsForIncubator getSettings(String[] args) {
        // logic to get settings
        return null;
    }

    public void stop() {
        this.active = false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MedicalProcessor processor = new MedicalProcessor();
        processor.start(args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but the loop function and my main function uses the same inherent structure. While encapsulating global variable limits the scope of it at first sight, in reality all of the functions in my main function might need settings. so probably I will need to put all of my main(args) inside loop(args).

Comment: as another side question, what would be the benefit of this architecture? I assume it is good because it basically means that the code outside of loop() will not see the "setting" variable.

Comment: this architecture didn't block main thread, you can do anything on main thread, and this architecture make your program stoppable when you need by call 'stop' function